# how to connect two tables from two different databases from two different servers- in SQL?

Tags: sql

I need to connect two tables from two different databases in two different servers in SQL.
I can't seem to do it. Can anyone help please?
Thanks

Comment: MSSQL Server? Use linked server feature.

Comment: ok, thanks. I am actually new to SQL, so, haven't got a clue how to use linked server:) Is there a link you are aware a novice like me can use to  pick it up easily?

Comment: http://www.databasejournal.com/features/mssql/article.php/3691721/Setting-up-a-Linked-Server-for-a-Remote-SQL-Server-Instance.htm

Comment: Please confirm the database vendor - is it Microsoft SQL Server?

Answer (score 0):

You need to add a linked server.

To access table `T_Users` on database catalog `COR_Basic` on server `CORDB2005` with user `ApertureWebServicesDE` (on `CORDB2005`) and password `MY_TOP_SECRET_PASSWORD` you would use:

```
EXEC master.dbo.sp_addlinkedserver 
    @server = N'RemoteDB'
   ,@srvproduct = 'OLE DB Provider for SQL'
   ,@provider = N'SQLNCLI'
   ,@datasrc = 'CORDB2005'
   ,@catalog = 'COR_Basic'

GO

EXEC master.dbo.sp_addlinkedsrvlogin 
    @rmtsrvname = N'RemoteDB'
   ,@useself = false
   --,@locallogin = 'LocalIntegrationUser'
   ,@locallogin = NULL 
   ,@rmtuser = N'ApertureWebServicesDE'
   ,@rmtpassword = N'MY_TOP_SECRET_PASSWORD'
GO




SELECT * 
FROM RemoteDB.COR_Basic.dbo.T_Users
```

Make sure that user ApertureWebServicesDE has all the rights to login and actually query the table on that server.

It goes without speaking that there needs to be a LAN/WAN connection between the two servers.

Also, if you want to link to stored-procedures, you need to enable them:

```
EXEC sp_serveroption @server='RemoteDB', @optname='rpc', @optvalue='true'
EXEC sp_serveroption @server='RemoteDB', @optname='rpc out', @optvalue='true'
```